# How can I know that the field is set to null?

Tags: json, go

I want to output an error if the field in json contains a value of null. How can I do it? I have tried "encoding/json". Maybe I need another library.

Code example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Item struct {
    Value  *int
}


func main() {
    var jsonBlob = `[
        {},
        {"Value": null},
        {"Value": 0},
        {"Value": 1}
    ]`
    var items []Item

    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonBlob)).Decode(&items)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    for _, a := range items {
        if a.Value != nil {
            fmt.Println(*a.Value)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(a.Value)
        }
    }
}
```

I got:

```
<nil>
<nil>
0
1
```

I want:

```
<nil>
<error>
0
1
```

Please help. Many thanks!

Comment: Why would `"Value": null` result in an error? `null` is a perfectly valid value for a pointer field, and correctly deserializes to `nil`, which is Go's `null`.

Comment: I am writing rest-api. This is one of the requirements.

Comment: @Ilya: this seems like an odd requirement for an API, `null` and unset are often the same thing.

Comment: @JimB: This is the API for the competition. I can not do anything about it. As I understand, such a request ( curl -i http://localhost:80/items/1 -d '{  "value": null}' ) says that you need to reset the value, which means that the request is not correct and the service should return an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to control how a type is unmarshaled, you can implement [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)

Since a map allows you to tell the difference between an unset value, and a `null` value, unmarshaling first into a generic `map[string]interface{}` will allow you to inspect the values without tokenizing the JSON.

```
type Item struct {
    Value *int
}


func (i *Item) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    tmp := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    val, ok := tmp["Value"]
    if ok && val == nil {
        return errors.New("Value cannot be nil")

    }
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    f, ok := val.(float64)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected type %T for Value", val)
    }

    n := int(f)
    i.Value = &n
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MNDsQpfEJA

Comment: I don't think this works, per the question, they want the zero value to be `nil` but `null` value to result in an error, per the "I want" section in the question.

Comment: @Ilya: I've updated with a map example, which shows how to differentiate "unset" vs "null"

Comment: @JimB: Thank you very much! But it seems this will seriously slow down the processing of the request.

Comment: @Ilya: have you tested how much it will slow it down? It will add some allocations, but encoding/json isn't particularly fast. If you want performance, you will need a different package, or write one to handle this specific case.

Comment: @JimB: It slowed down 2.5 times. Can you advise something?

Comment: @Ilya: 2.5 times what? If it's still running in microseconds, that's not much compared to an actual http request. As I mentioned, if you need more performance, feel free to write your own decoder to handle this specific case. It seems this may be the purpose of this example in the game, and I don't have time right now to write your competition entry for you.

Comment: @JimB: I did a cycle of 100,000 operations. The original version is executed for 500ms, and the version with a string map is executed for 1300ms. Nevermind. Can you explain this line `f, ok := val.(float64)`? It seemed to me that I should use something like this `f, ok := strconv.Atoi(val.(string))`.

Comment: @Ilya: A JSON number is a double precision float, so the default type is `float64`. You can't assert it as a string when it's not a string. If the number were stored in a quoted string in the JSON, then yes you would have to assert it as a string and convert it to an integer.

Comment: @JimB: Thank you! I thought that all the values are represented by string. My mistake, I'm inattentive.